# How to get the EntityID for Quickbooks online?

Tags: api, quickbooks-online

I am looking at the API explorer for Quickbooks Online here: 
https://developer.intuit.com/v2/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO#?id=Account

Every request requires an entitiyId field, but I have no idea what this ID is.  Where do i get it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

EntityId is the QBO-service generated an internal object identifier.

You can use the query endpoint to fetch all account records which will have the entity-specific ids. 
Ex - https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/explore-the-quickbooks-online-api/data-queries

You might find the following tutorial useful.
https://developer.intuit.com/hub/blog/2017/08/03/quick-start-quickbooks-online-rest-api-oauth-2-0

Comment: Please do not sign your posts here - thanks. Profile cards are widely considered to be a sufficient signature.